# WordPress: Why does this error occurs [twitch]

Tags: wordpress, twitch

[image]

I am trying to embed twitch on WordPress, I have used an iframe to embed it and also I have changed example.com to my domain name still getting this, what can be the possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain must use SSL Certificate